# Rspec with Devise in request specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I am writing request specs in which I have to authenticate a devise user.

I have rails = 5.2 & ruby 2.6.1

I followed the instructions given [Here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-sign-in-and-out-a-user-in-Request-type-specs-(specs-tagged-with-type:-:request)#1-simple-approach) and use simple approach.

In added the line below in my spec/rails_helper.rb

```sh
config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
```

spec/requests/securities_spec.rb

```sh
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'Security APIs', type: :request do

  let!(:security) {FactoryBot.create(:security)}
  let!(:research) {FactoryBot.create(:research, name: Faker::Company.bs, security_type_id: security.security_type_id)}
  let!(:research_result) {FactoryBot.create(:research_result, name: Faker::Company.bs, sub_category_total: Faker::Number.number(digits: 2), securities_total: Faker::Number.number(digits: 2), research_id: research.id )}
  let!(:research_active) {FactoryBot.create(:research_active, security_type_id: security.security_type_id)}

  describe 'Get /securitiees' do
    it 'will return securites' do
      @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
      sign_in @user
      get "/securities"
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
      expect(JSON.parse(response.body).size).to eq(2)
    end
  end
end
```

But when I run  sign_in @user I get

> [#Proc:0x00005630eaf015d8@/home/humayun/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/test/helpers.rb:19]

I check the above response by adding a debugger before sign_in.

in my securities_controller.rb I'm authenticating the user by

> before_action :authenticate_user!

I don't know why this is not working any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you check if `@user` got created successfully? your code looks correct so the `sign_in` shouldn't have any issues unless `@user` has isssues.

Comment: @SachinSingh yes my user-created successfully but problems occur when I want to sign_in

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue if not the same issue.

I had been trying to use this:

```rb
config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :request
```

It worked when i changed it to this:

```rb
config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
```

I believe request specs count as integration tests. in the source it says:

> ...Do not use `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` in integration tests...
> [devise...controller_helpers.rb](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/8593801130f2df94a50863b5db535c272b00efe1/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb)

[devise#integration-tests](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#integration-tests)